# Not able to run a Flutter iOS App when added sqlflite plugin

Tags: ios, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

When I added the sqflite plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to my project, as well as the path plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/path), the *pod install* command is not running anymore.

```
CocoaPods' output:

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: Function not implemented @ rb_file_s_symlink - (/Users/jairrillojunior/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/,
/Users/jairrillojunior/Box/IBM - Documents/Flutter/flutter_sqflite/ios/.symlinks/plugins/sqflite).

 #  from /Users/jairrillojunior/Box/IBM - Documents/Flutter/flutter_sqflite/ios/Podfile:34
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #
 >    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:318:in `rescue in block in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:312:in `block in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:310:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:310:in `from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:276:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11.

flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-4.0.pre.122, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021 darwin-x64, locale en-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-4.0.pre.122 at /usr/local/flutter
    • Framework revision 4aad058a49 (22 minutes ago), 2020-10-28 17:02:37 -0400
    • Engine revision 64e6599910
    • Dart version 2.11.0 (build 2.11.0-260.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jairrillojunior/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/jairrillojunior/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.1, Build version 12A7403
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 (mobile) • 351AEE81-599C-42E6-BEDB-46FD919491D9 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Also, the Podfile generated by the plugins:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of `Sqflite` and `Path` plugin have you defined in `pubspec.yaml`?
Asking this because you should not mention any version, according to this tutorial by **Flutter** .
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Comment: I am following the same link and the plugins do not have versions like the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.

The problem reported by myself happened due the directory name/location (probably the space among the names).

Moving to another location (not containing spaces) the build works fine.